# Script reads data but not changing it

Tags: google-apps-script, range, overwrite

My code seems to be working but obviously I am missing a trick.

```
        function booleanToNumerics(){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1--wLf-_CcfsF_7mn4SaAyqgw_G6Jvkymp7qw8DgjhOU");
    var shCS = ss.getSheetByName("CS-CLEAN");
    var lastRow = shCS.getLastRow();
    var lastCol = shCS.getLastColumn();
    var shData = shCS.getRange(2,3,lastRow,lastCol).getValues();
    var changeData = shData.toString().replace("FALSE", "X");

      Logger.log(changeData)

      return changeData;

      shCS.getRange(2,3,lastRow,lastCol).setValues(changeData);

}
```

When I view the log, it is reading the sheet but when I ask it to write the data it isn't doing anything obvious (i.e. what I want). Can anyone point me towards the answer or a resource that will explain why I am failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you retrieve all values and want to replace each field that has `"FALSE"` value with `"X"` values.

With `.getValues()` you retrieve a bidimensional array such as

```
[[1,2,"FALSE"],["4","5","FALSE"]]
```

Of course, depending on the number of cols and rows in the sheet.

Then you convert it to a string with `.toString()` and it becomes

```
"1,2,FALSE,4,5,FALSE"
```

Then, with the `.replace()` method, you obtain something like

```
"1,2,X,4,5,FALSE"
```

Three things are happening here

1/ As soon as `toString` is called, every property of an array is lost.

To solve this, you need to actually call `JSON.stringify` on your array

2/ You are not replacing **ALL** occurrences of `FALSE`, just the first one

To solve this, you need to use a bit of regex, like this
`str = str.replace(/abc/g, '');`

Afterwards, you need to convert your string into a valid array, achieved with `JSON.parse` method

3/ You `return` **before** setting the values. This causes the function to terminate when you don't want to.

Fixing all these issues will give you this, which should work properly:

```
function booleanToNumerics(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1xRKM7BlAgwYWuLdCqMOd5qwmiy4i1d8bXxZWU7rJfE4");
var shCS = ss.getSheetByName("CS-CLEAN");
var lastRow = shCS.getLastRow();
var lastCol = shCS.getLastColumn();
var shData = shCS.getRange(2,3,lastRow,lastCol).getValues();
var regexToUse = /false/g, valToReplaceWith = new String("X");
var changeData = JSON.stringify(shData).replace(regexToUse, '"'+valToReplaceWith+'"');

Logger.log(changeData)

shCS.getRange(2,3,lastRow,lastCol).setValues(JSON.parse(changeData));

return changeData;
}
```